# Showing that a group of functions is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's consider the group of real numbers with addition $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$. Moreover we have a group $\hat{G} = \big \{\xi: G \mapsto \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1 \}\big \}$ with the operation of multiplication of elements from $\hat{G}$.

We know that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\xi(x) = e^{itx}, \quad \forall \, \xi \in \hat{G}.$$

I am to show that $G$ and $\hat{G}$ are isomorphic.

I know that I am to find a function $f: G \mapsto \hat{G}$ such that $f$ is isomorphic and $f(x + y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)$. I thought that maybe $f(x) = e^{ix}$ might be correct but that function isn't even close to being bijective.

I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: You should be showing that these groups are non-isomorphic, but $\hat{G}\cong G/{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you explain you statement a bit more, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that $f(x)$ must be an element of $\hat{G}$, hence a morphism and not a number. Thus $f(x)= e^{ix}$ is not a possible solution.

Let $f : G \to \hat{G}$, $x \mapsto \xi_x$ where $\xi_x : (\Bbb  R,+) \to \{ z \in \Bbb C : \ |z|=1 \}$, $t \mapsto e^{itx}$. You could try to see if $f$ is a group isomorphism.

Comment: However the map $t \mapsto e^{itx}$ is not bijective. Why can we consider it to be an isomorphism?

Comment: This map correspond to $f(x)=\xi_x$ and is simply a group morphism (which is surjective but not injective yes), but the goal is to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism not that $f(x)$ is an isomorphism right? So you have to see if the map $f$ that i defined is a group morphism that is injective and surjective. It is injective since the only way $\xi_x(t)=1$ $\forall t$ is when $x=0$. I didn't check the surjectivity.

Comment: The group $\hat G$ is defined to be the group of *homomorphisms* from $G$ to $S^1$ right? Its not the set of all functions from $G$ to $S^1$!?

Comment: I understood the question that way, $\hat{G}=Hom(G,S^1)$, otherwise I don't think there is an isomorphism with $G$. Do you think I should use the word morphism instead of function in the answer?